# How to find out which (version of a) function is being used?

Tags: r, debugging

**Question:**

How can I find out which version of a function is being called? For example, if I use `unique` on a data.frame, I presume that I am using `unique.data.frame`. However, there is no `unique.raster` function, although there is a `raster::unique`. But if I use, e.g., `trace(unique)`, I only get information that the `unique` function is being used.

I'd like to confirm, for example, that when I call `unique(data.frame(1))`, `unique.data.frame` is being called.

**Example:**

I am having trouble figuring out why `unique(raster_object)` works at the command line but not inside a function. Apparently, `unique.default` is being called inside the function, so I would like to explicitly state which `unique.&

For example this works:

```
library(raster)
a <- rasterFromXYZ(data.frame(a=1:2,b=2:3,c=3:4))
unique(a)
```

But when I put this in a function:

```
myfun <- function(){
  a <- rasterFromXYZ(data.frame(a=1:2,b=2:3,c=3:4))
  b <- crop(a, extent(c(1,2,3,4)))
  unique(a)
}
```

even if the package uses `raster` as a dependency, after I build the package and load it in a new R session, I get the error:

```
> myfun()
Error in unique.default(a) : unique() applies only to vectors
```

Even though `sessionInfo()` shows that the raster package is loaded.

and if I use `debug(unique)`, it doesn't seem to be telling me which function is being called:

```
Browse[6]> unique(a)
Error in unique.default(a) : unique() applies only to vectors
Browse[6]> raster::unique(a)
debugging in: raster::unique(a)
debug: standardGeneric("unique")
```

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem, but generally you can call `debug(unique)` and then make your `unique` call and step through (by typing "n") to see what functions get called

Comment: @eddi to reproduce, you can try `library(devtools); install_github("rhwsd", "dlebauer", ref = "717c18f5"); library(rhwsd); myfun()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 myfun <- function(){
   a <- rasterFromXYZ(data.frame(a=1:2,b=2:3,c=3:4))
   b <- crop(a, extent(c(1,2,3,4)))
   raster::unique(a)
 }
 myfun()
#[1] 3 4
```

If there were a `unique.raster` dispatched in the S3 system, you could have used `trace(unique)`, but since the `unique` method for class "rasterLayer" is an S4 function, that won't work:

```
> showMethods("unique")
Function: unique (package base)
x="ANY", incomparables="ANY"
x="character", incomparables="missing"
    (inherited from: x="ANY", incomparables="ANY")
x="numeric", incomparables="missing"
    (inherited from: x="ANY", incomparables="ANY")
x="RasterLayer", incomparables="missing"
x="RasterStackBrick", incomparables="missing"
```

Use it's package location:

```
> trace("unique", browser, where=raster)
Tracing function "unique" as seen from package "raster"
[1] "unique"
> myfun()
Tracing unique(xyz[, 1]) on entry 
Called from: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
Browse[1]> 
Browse[1]> c
[1] 3 4
> untrace()
Error in methods::.TraceWithMethods(where = <environment>, untrace = TRUE) : 
  argument "what" is missing, with no default
> untrace("unique",  where=raster)
Untracing function "unique" as seen from package "raster"
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer - I was able to come up with this workaround, but my real question was what debugging tools would help me to identify when/if `raster::unique` was being called.

Comment: thanks for the clarification - I didn't realize that this was a fundamental difference in the way S3 and S4 methods are used.