# Lacking any imports (install/attach), how does one determine the function about to be called?

Tags: r

Briefly...

You just started an R session. You're about to call function `foo()`. How do you determine which function `foo()` you will be calling?

(Also) related:

- [How to find out which (version of a) function is being used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19259512/9295807)

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. R functions have namespaces, not paths; use the `namespace::func()` convention to specify exactly which function you want to call.

Comment: @HongOoi I removed unix from the question, and I made the question briefer and simpler. Is what I'm asking for clear now?

Comment: `environment(foo)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to check that I can think of straight up, view the function itself...

```
predict

# function (object, ...) 
# UseMethod("predict")
# <bytecode: 0x2f5f808>
# <environment: namespace:stats>
```

Another to check the `environment`

```
environment(fun = predict)

# <environment: namespace:stats>
```

These both reveal the namespace where the function resides.

> **N.B.** Some functions may not be as clear, such as primitives
>   `max # function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("max")`
>   But you could assume these are `base`.

Comment: True. Merely typing the function's name, rather than calling it, will reveal its source. This is also quite a terrible way. Even if the function is trivial, I'm out fishing by my eyes precisely which punctuation symbol (etc) I have modified, and to determine by comparison with the source listing whether it's the current version or the installed version (of a function in a package).

Comment: Can you share the second method you were thinking of?